# How to fix 'Cannot read property 'channel' of undefined' while using Node.JS and Discord.JS?

Tags: node.js

I'm building my first Discord bot, and I seem to have run into a snag. While making a ping command, I have run into a TypeError, which is in the title. My problem is, is that both the command, and the 'undefined' object are defined. The problem code is below. I am a new programmer to Node.JS so I am looking for help on how to fix this for the future as well.

I've tried to change the order in which the commands are read from, and have asked other more senior programmers for help. Again, very new to Node.JS, so not good at debugging it.

```
//Ping Command
function pingCommand(receivedMessage) {
    const pingmessage = receivedMessage.channel.send('Pinging...')
    pingmessage.edit(`Estimated ping: ${receivedMessage.createdTimestamp - pingmessage.createdTimestamp}ms, bot ping is ${Math.round(client.ping)}ms `)

}
```

I am expecting the bot to paste inside of my designated command channel the ping of the bot, which at this point is irrelevant, because I get an error every time the code is run.

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'channel' of undefined

Comment: probably `receivedMessage` is `undefined` meaning when you're calling `pingCommand`, you're not passing any value

Comment: @naga-elixir-jar there is another command above `pingCommand` that does work with `receivedMessage`

Comment: can you put `console.log(receivedMessage)` inside pingCommand as the first statement, and verify

Comment: can't, the code says that console.log is never read, and says there's problems with the code

Comment: @Creeperguy05 what do you pass to `pingCommand` when called?